# Green’s function of $\delta(t_1 - t_2) \frac{d}{d t_2}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematics, greens-functions, dirac-delta-distributions

Does anyone know how to find the Green function for this operator?

$$\delta(t_1 - t_2) \frac{d}{d t_2}.$$

Where we should have something like
$$\int dt_2 \delta(t_1 - t_2) \frac{d}{d t_2} G(t_2,t_3) = \delta(t_1 - t_3).$$

And/or any pertinent identities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\int dt_2 \delta (t_1-t_2)\frac{d}{dt_2}G(t_2,t_3)=\frac{d}{dt_1}G(t_1,t_3)$$

So the equation is

$$\frac{d}{dt_1}G(t_1,t_3)=\delta (t_1-t_3)$$

This has a simple solution:

$$G(t_1,t_3)=\theta(t_1-t_3)$$

Where $\theta(t_1-t_3)=0$ when $t_1<t_3$ and $\theta(t_1-t_3)=1$ when $t_1>t_3$. This is the so called Heaviside step function.